# problem with Flickering of text on mouse move?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseevent

I have some html snippet which is initally hidden

```
<p style="float: left; position: relative; left: 130px; top: 80px; display: none;" id="homehref">    
    <a href="" style="color: white;">Home Page</a>
</p>
```

i show it with jQuery.show(); on mouseover and again hide it on mouseout with jQuery.hide(); altough i seee flickering of text when i place the mouse over the element has anyone faced same issue before.

Comment: you show it on `mouseover` of what. If it is `display:none` no events are fired for `mouseover`..

Comment: How can you hover on a hidden element?

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I show it on mouseover of some other element on the page and hide it again when i do mouseout.

Comment: You should post your jQuery and CSS also.

Comment: Please post more code, you cannot hover on something that is display:none; - I need a little more to work with!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additional `mouseover` and `mouseout` events are fired on your outer element because of [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

You should bind to [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead of `mouseover`/`mouseout` to prevent that:

> The `mouseleave` event differs from
>   `mouseout` in the way it handles event
>   bubbling. If `mouseout` were used in
>   this example, then when the mouse
>   pointer moved out of the **Inner**
>   element, the handler would be
>   triggered. This is usually undesirable
>   behavior. The `mouseleave` event, on
>   the other hand, only triggers its
>   handler when the mouse leaves the
>   element it is bound to, not a
>   descendant. So in this example, the
>   handler is triggered when the mouse
>   leaves the **Outer** element, but not the
>   **Inner** element.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead of `mouseout`. You could also use [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$('#someOtherElement').hover(function() {
    $('#homeref').toggle();
});
```